# Is mock configuration propagated to other threads in mockito?

Tags: java, multithreading, mockito

I have a test consisting of a thread running test code and another thread running the system under test. The SuT contains some mocks being configured in test thread.

The behavior of my test is: It does on my local machine what it should. On our build server it doesn't. As far I have debugged, the problem is, that mock doesn't behave like configured.

So it seems to me like my configuration from test thread (in some circumstances) is not propagated to sut thread.

Could this be the problem? Is Mockito not thread-safe in such use cases?
Here's some example code, working on my machine and (unluckily) on our build server, too.

```
@Test
public void testConcurrency() throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    MyService serviceMock = mock(MyService.class);
    MyApplication app = new MyApplication(serviceMock);
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(app);

    when(serviceMock.call()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("expected exception"));

    String result = future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertNotNull(result);
}

public class MyApplication implements Callable<String> {
    private final MyService myService;

    public MyApplication(MyService myService) {
        super();
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            while(true) {
                myService.call();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "42";
        }
    }
}

public static interface MyService {
    String call();
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. A mock is some instance of an object and you can setup some behavior on **this** instance. So I don't understand what you mean by propagation

Comment: maybe add some example tests of both threads which doesn´t work like you want.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model

Comment: What's the behavior on the build server? null is returned instead of "42"?

Comment: As wroten the simple testcase above behaves correct. But adapted to the my real testcase the exception is not thrown

Answer (score 1):

I've had an issue when the mock behaves like it wasn't configured properly.
So the interceptors were not invoked when calling the mocked object's stubbed method in other thread. I've understand that Mockito resets my stubs when accessing the mock inside of other thread. Try to use the following.

```
@MockBean(reset = MockReset.NONE)
MyService myService
```

It may lead to problems if you have many tests in a row, but I'm not sure. And if you have 1 test it will "propagate" (do not reset) your mocks behaviour (stubs) to (in) another threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, Mockito does not propagate configuration to other threads and can not do it by design, because Mockito stores configurations in LocalThread.

I don't know any way to share configuration between threads.

You can try another mock-library, for example EasyMock - it has another design, and PROBABLY is "thread-safe", in your sin